# Is there any way to dump physical ROM memory in android

Tags: android, u-boot, rom, android-rom

Most of partitions in android can be copied by mounting partition and then using `dd` command. But in case I want to copy area memory of uboot, That solution can't resolve. My question is that is there anyway I can dump whole ROM memory in an android device ? By that way, I can copy partition of uboot and flash it to another device. Thank All !

Comment: dd can do both: copy partitions and copy whole devices

Comment: I often copy partitions using ```dd``` command but I don't know how i can use it to cope whole ROM memory ?

Comment: dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system of=foo will copy the whole system device without mounting any partition.